# Storyboard and iPhone 6 landscape only

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, size-classes, iphone-6-plus

Suppose if we are designing storyboard to support iPhone6 Plus in landscape only orientation, which one of the below vertical and horizontal size class combination 
we choose and why

a. Regular Vertical and Compact Horizontal size class

b. Regular Vertical and Regular Horizontal size class

c. Compact Vertical and Regular Horizontal size class

d. Compact Vertical and Compact Horizontal size class

Comment: dd you refer size classes guide???

Comment: Yeah but its confusing ! Can you guide me through ?

Comment: iPhone 6 maens 4.7inch....means `Any Width|compact Height` for landscape...iPhone 6 plus means 5.5inch ....i.e  `Regular  Width|compact Height` for landscape...hope this clears your doubt

Comment: @EICaptain - Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iphone6 plus landscape, Regular Width(Horizontal) and Compact Height(Vertical).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The available screen size for a view controller is based on three factors:

1.) The screen size of the device.

2.) The orientation of the device.

3.) The portion of the screen available to the view controller. For example, when a split view controller displays both the master and detail controllers, neither controller has access to the full screen.

BTW For iPhone6 plus landscape mode, preferable size class is: **Regular Width and Compact Height**.

For more details: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

&

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html